# Uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

I am having trouble proving a simple proposition regarding uniform convergence and pointwise convergence in **Real Analysis**.

**Problem:**

Suppose that $\left(f_{n}\right)$ is a sequence of functions $f_{n}: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\left(f_{n}\right)$ **converges uniformly** to $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $\left(f_{n}\right)$ also converges **pointwise** to $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

**Relevant definitions/Notations:**

One says that $f_{n} \rightarrow f$ **uniformly** on $A$ if, for every $\epsilon>0,$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N$ implies that $$\left|f_{n}(x)-f(x)\right|<\epsilon$$ for all $x \in A$.

Finally, we say that $f_{n} \rightarrow f$ **pointwise** on $A$ if, given $\epsilon>0,$ for each $x \in A$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N$ implies that $$\left|f_{n}(x)-f(x)\right|<\epsilon$$

**Attempts:**

I tried to write down the definition of uniform convergence and then arguing that, in particular, since $N \in \mathbb{N}$ from uniform convergence works for any given point in $x \in A$, then it must work for a given point and from that conclude pointwise convergence.

I also checked some proofs like the one that states that uniform continuity implies continuity and write something similar, but i just dont know how to do it.

I would highly appreciate a detailed proof regarding this fact, i am trying to become proeficient at proof writing.

Thanks in advance, Lucas

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your argument? From the description it sounds fine. There's really not much to the proof. In a nutshell, if $f_n \to f$ uniformly, then given $\epsilon > 0$ you can choose the same $N$ for every $x$ in the definition of pointwise convergence.

Comment: In fact, what i did was write down the definition of uniform convergence and then wrote down that "in particular, since $N \in \mathbb{N}$ from uniform convergence works for any given point in $x \in A$, then it must work for a given point and from that conclude pointwise convergence."

Comment: But in the task, i am supposed to explicitly write every quantifier and etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt looks fine. Take $x\in A$; you want to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$. Now, take $\varepsilon>0$; you want to prove that there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that$$n\geqslant N\implies\bigl|f_n(x)-f(x)\bigr|<\varepsilon.\tag1$$So, take $N\in\Bbb N$ such that$$(\forall a\in A)(\forall n\in\Bbb N):n\geqslant N\implies\bigl|f_n(a)-f(a)\bigr|<\varepsilon.$$It follows from this that, for such a $N$, $(1)$ holds.

Comment: Is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ the one from the uniform convergence?

Comment: Yes! That's what I wrote: it's the same $N$.

Comment: That confuses me a lot. Since $N$ was chosen from uniform convergence, it is such that $N = N(\epsilon)$ only, whereas in pointwise convergence this number should be a function of $\epsilon$ and $a \in A$

Comment: That is the reason why i am a little fearful of choosing the same $N$, as it would not be a function of both parameters required for the pointwise convergence

Comment: The function $f(x,y)=x$ is formally a function of $x$ and $y$ but, in fact, it depends only on $x$. It's the same thing here. In general, $N$ *may* depend on $\varepsilon$ and on $a$, but it doesn't *have* to.

Comment: hmmmmmmm, that final explanation was key!

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, it is useful to remind that uniform convergence is equivalent to convergence with respect to the sup norm.

Having said that, let $f_{n}:(X,d_{X})\to(Y,d_{Y})$ converges uniformly to $f:(X,d_{X})\to(Y,d_{Y})$.

Thus for every $\varepsilon > 0$ and every $x\in X$ there corresponds $n_{\varepsilon} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that we have that
\begin{align*}
n\geq n_{\varepsilon} & \Rightarrow d_{Y}(f_{n}(x),f(x)) \leq \sup_{x\in X}d_{Y}(f_{n}(x),f(x)) \leq \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Hence $f_{n}$ converges to $f$ point-wise.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Useful answer! Nevertheless, my intent was to prove the statement without making any other assumptions. But it helped anyways! Thank you for your time