# If $||f_n-f||_{\infty}\to 0 $ and $V[f_n-f; a,b] \to 0$, then does $f_n\to f$ pointwise everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $V[f_n-f;a,b]$ denote the total variation of $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ over $[a,b]$.

If $||f_n-f||_{\infty}\to 0 $ and $V[f_n-f; a,b] \to 0$, then does $f_n \to f$ pointwise everywhere (I know $||f_n - f||_\infty \to 0$ is enough for almost everywhere convergence, but does the extra condition guarantee everywhere convergence)?

If so, how do I show this?

NOTE:

$||f||_\infty = \text{esssup}_{x\in E} |f(x)|$ and $||f||_u = \sup_{x \in X} |f(x)|$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3980377/uniform-convergence-implies-pointwise-convergence

Comment: $||\cdot||_u$ is the uniform norm. I thought convergence in $||\cdot||_\infty$ was weaker than convergence in $||\cdot||_u$ so I thought you needed more than just $||f_n-f||_\infty \to 0$.

Comment: But I do know that convergence in $||\cdot||_\infty$ implies almost uniform convergence. Is that enough?

Comment: Convergence in the $L^{\infty}$ norm only gives uniform convergence up to measure zero sets. So no it doesn’t say anything about those remaining points. If you have continuity or something else then yes.

Comment: It would help if you add your exact definitions of $\Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty$ and $\Vert \cdot \Vert_u$ to the question.

Comment: I see. That's why I was wondering if the extra condition gave us some information about those remaining points. If the $f_n$ were continuous, say, then how can we conclude the "yes" part?

Comment: $||f||_\infty = \text{esssup}_{x\in E} |f(x)|$ and $||f||_u = \sup_{x \in X} |f(x)|$.

Comment: If $g$ is continuous at a point $a$ and $g(a)\neq 0$, then there’s a neighborhood on which $g$ doesn’t vanish, i.e a positive measure set on which $g$ is non-zero.

Comment: More generally, if $f_n(c) \to f(c)$ at _a single point_ $c \in [a,b]$ and $V(f_n-f,a,b) \to 0$, then $f_n \to f$ uniformly in $[a,b]$.  This is just the triangle inequality in disguise.

Comment: Thank you. I had an argument that I deleted for some reason showing that - $||f_n-f||_u \leq V[f-f_n; a,b] + |f(x)-f_n(x)| \to |f(x)-f_n(x)|$ for $x \in [a,b]$ so if it converges at a point, then it does converge uniformly everywhere. Going back to the $f_n$ continuous case, though, I'm not quite sure I understand the argument that's being hinted.

Comment: Wait, actually, I think I understand now - that if there is a point $x$ where it fails to converge, then $f_n-f$ will be nonzero on a set of positive measure even for large $n$, a contradiction. $f-f_n$ is continuous since if $f_n \to f$ uniformly, $f$ will be continuous.